# WCF service is working on dev server but on production it is not woking

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a .net client and I am consuming the WCF service and able to do that sucessfully. but when i try to post that on our production I am not able to consume the same service. Below is my web.config :

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyBehavior">
      <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress></useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="TestProject.Implementations.AuthenticateUser,TestProject"/>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="TestProject.Implementations.ServiceCustom" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SampleServiceBinding" contract="TestProject.Interfaces.IServiceCustom"></endpoint>
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SampleServiceBinding">
      <security mode ="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

and also I want to make my service HTTPS enabled.

I get below errormessage:
There was no endpoint listening at http://url.com that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Comment: "See InnerException, if present, for more details." Can we see it too?

Comment: Your `web.config` contains no address for the web service. Even so, the error means that you change the target URL in your code, perhaps using a configured value with `url.com` as the default value. Without posting the *actual code* that causes the error, it's impossible to help

Comment: Add the app.config from the client, or the code the client uses to connect to the service. But i guess the problem is, that you did not specify an address for the endpoint which is serving your contract.

Answer (score 0):

This error clearly suggest that the WCF service you are trying to access is not clearly hosted, or the address you are using to connect to is not pointing to the service, make sure by using the address in a browser you are able to access that service.

If you are able to access the service , check your client application web.config and find out the end point details for that service. If the endpoint url is mismatched you may get this error.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?. Please add comment on how did you solve this so that someone can learn from your question. Do not forget to up vote or accept the answer provided by stack overflow members. If the answer is incorrect or not useful you can also down vote the answer.

Comment: I fixed the error and below is the web config code:

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error and below is the web config code:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyBehavior">
<useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress></useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"  />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="TestProject.Implementations.AuthenticateUser,TestProject"/>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="TestProject.Implementations.Test" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior">
    <endpoint address="http://rul" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SampleServiceBinding" contract="TestProject.Interfaces.Test"></endpoint>
<endpoint address="https:url" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SampleServiceBindingHttps" contract="TestProject.Interfaces.ITest"></endpoint>
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpsBinding" address="mex"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SampleServiceBinding">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
<binding name="SampleServiceBindingHttps">
  <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
  </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I changed the security mode to TransportWithMessageCredential mode and change few config like binding = "mexHttpsBinding"